# Android - Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, exception, xamarin

I was trying to implement a NavigationDrawer in my `C#` Android project. So I have created a seperate project especially for the NavigationDrawer just to be more comfortable in writing and editing the code for this Naviugation. Everything worked fine in this project and the NavigationDrawer is well displayed, now I came to my original project(which contains a lot more layouts and activities) and copied all the necessary activities, packages and layouts then I successfully rebuild the project with no errors but when I run it to see the results I got this annoying exception:

> Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton

**Here where I am getting the exception in my MainActivity:**

```
Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.app_bar);
SetSupportActionBar(toolbar); // In this line
```

**Here is my layout (where I defined the Toolbar):**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include layout="@layout/app_bar"/>
```

I searched online on this exception but nothing helped me. In addition, I have checked all the packages, they are the same as the second demo Navigation project. So I am sure about packages. I don't have a clue about what may be causing this exception. Would you please help me to find out and solve my problem ?

Comment: compare your code and check -> https://medium.com/@101/android-toolbar-for-appcompatactivity-671b1d10f354

Comment: @SushiHangover yea it is subclassing from `AppCompatActivity`, it is already working in my demo project. I just copied the code

Comment: @SushiHangover `v4.0.30319` in the two projects

Comment: @Wassim01 ?... should a version like: `27.0.2`

Comment: @SushiHangover `v4.0.30319` is the runtime version which appears in the properties window. The `version` I have is `25.4.0.2` also in the two projects. And I can't update it cause it will give me `You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that ..`. But I have `Crosslight.Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat` package installed.

Comment: Are your all `Android.Support` packages are 25.4.0.2? If the versions are different could also cause this problem.

Comment: @Billy Yes they are all 25.4.0.2